# Using Java 8 how can I get count of consecutive characters in a string

Tags: string, java-8, java-stream

Using Java 8 how can I get count of consecutive characters in a string. like

String str = "aabbbccddbb";
// output: 2a3b2c2d2b

Please note that count of b is not 5

```
// I was able to do it with this. But how can we achieve it using Java 8
String str = "aabbbccddbb";
int count = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) {
    if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1)) {
        count++;
    } else {
        System.out.print(count+ ""+str.charAt(i));
        count = 1;
    }
}
System.out.print(count+""+str.charAt(str.length()-1));
```

Comment: This is a question or an answer?

Comment: I think OP wants the code re-written using streams.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your ultimate goal, you don't have to count the characters. You can split between different adjacent characters and then use the length of each substring.

- `(?<=(.))` - a zero width look behind for a character, captured in the capture group.
- `(?!\\1)` - followed by any negative zero-width look ahead for a different character from the one just captured (using a back reference `\\1`to capture group one).
- then map each sub-string to its length followed by the first character of the string.
- and join each sub-result with a collector.

```
String str = "aabbbccddbb";
String result = Arrays.stream(str.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)"))
        .map(s -> s.length() + Character.toString(s.charAt(0)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
2a3b2c2d2b
```

If you don't want a number for single character sub-strings, you can change the map to this:

```
.map(s -> (s.length() > 1 ? s.length() : "")
                        + Character.toString(s.charAt(0)))
```

Comment: Instead of `Character.toString(s.charAt(0))` you can also write `s.substring(0, 1)`. Though, I’d rather use `s.length() + "" + s.charAt(0)` instead. Since Java 9, you can also achieve the same using `String result = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1*").matcher(str) .replaceAll(mr -> mr.end() - mr.start() + mr.group(1));`.

Comment: I especially  like your actual solution.  Was not aware of the `replaceAll` method of the `Matcher class`.  So much to learn ....